# Can I use Hoptoad iOS Notifier with a Titanium Appcelerator iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, titanium, appcelerator, crash-reports, hoptoad

Can I use Hoptoad iOS Notifier (sends iPhone error reports to developers) with a Titanium Appcelerator iPhone application? (http://hoptoadapp.com/pages/ios-notifier).

I cannot tell for sure from their website, but it looks like Hoptoad iOS Notifier is an Objective-C library, so I would assume not, but I wanted to check with more knowledgeable people.

If not, is there something else I can do to report user errors in a Titanium Appcelerator iPhone app?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to add custom native (Objective-C) iOS modules to your Titanium apps. Thus, creating such a module to interface with Hoptoad may be possible.

I do not think that Titanium has any error reporting modules like this yet. I am also interested in a tool like this, so I may look into creating a module for it (or let us know if you create one).

[Titanium's Module Developers Guide (PDF)](http://assets.appcelerator.com.s3.amazonaws.com/docs/Module_Developers_Guide_iOS.pdf) isn't the best, but it will get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [cloudebug](http://www.cloudebug.com/). It is a real-time, web-based debugging system designed for Titanium.

I haven't tried it yet, but it looks very easy to use.